# How to display img tag in conditional statement?

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

HI i have a list of items and i need to display that i am listing using ionic list so in my list item it contain image  or video 
json

```
"media": [{"type": "img","src": "http://images/2015/May/161887.jpg"},{"type": "video","src": "http:/video/2015/May/161887.mp4",}]
```

html code.

```
<div class="news_image" ng-repeat="image in item.media">
  {{ image.type=='video'? 'video':image.type=='<img src="{{ image.src}}'? 'image': 'default' }}
</div>
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good approach to your problem, with `ng-if` you can simply add/remove elements you need conditionally. And look at `ng-src`too that's the good way to inject URLs into `src`elements like `img`:

[NgIf doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/zwfcsa7d/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="news_image" ng-repeat="image in items.media">
        <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-if="image.type === 'img'" />
        <video ng-if="image.type === 'video'" width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source ng-src="{{image.src}}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = {
        "media": [{
            "type": "img",
            "src": "http://images/2015/May/161887.jpg"
        }, {
            "type": "video",
            "src": "http:/video/2015/May/161887.mp4",
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: It might be helpful to the OP to add a short explanation or point out the use of ngIf.

Comment: HI it is working fine for image but for vide video is not working.